# Swift 4 UiTextView - delete a word inside textView on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitextfielddelegate

Is there a way to delete a specific word inside a UITextView?
let's say for example that in a textView the user wrote: "Hello my nome is john".
As soon as he finished typing he noticed that he mistyped a word.
Lets' say that there is an array initialised with a set o word and "name" is one of this.
when the user go back with the cursor and start deleting the misspelled a list of suggestion comes up.
He detect the word name and click on it.
is there a way to delete the word nome and insert the word name on which he just clicked.
So basically is there a way to get the word immediately before the cursor and remove it from the text view?

I have been able to get the first word before the cursor:

```
func characterBeforeCursor() -> String? {

    // get the cursor position
    if let cursorRange = postTextField.selectedTextRange {

        // get the position one character before the cursor start position
        if let newPosition = postTextField.position(from: cursorRange.start, offset: -1) {

            let range = postTextField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: cursorRange.start)
            return postTextField.text(in: range!)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

but i wouldn't know how to get the entire word (until the first space, or a particular character e.g "@" ) and delte it from the textview.

I am a bit lost.... so Thanks to anyone will help.

Comment: Custom logic required to replace/delete tokenized strings. You may maintain a string token buffer, Update it when text is updated and replace the textview contents if needed.

Comment: @lal thx for your answer... I'm kind of new to swift... so i didn't really understand what you mean...could you be a bit more specific... sorry...